# Pressing Enter with AJAX Live Search

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, livesearch

I have an AJAX live search created and I need the ability to press Enter to search the word. Is there a reason why I can not find any AJAX Live Search bars with this function?

I created it using this tutorial
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp

Comment: "Is there a reason why I can not find any AJAX Live Search bars with this function?" - You are not looking hard enough.

Comment: Any chance you could point me in the right direction? I am really having trouble finding this.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like this http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/check it out

Comment: This is exactly my point. Any example I find, such as this one, does not have a functioning Enter key. It simply gives you the suggestions while you type. However if you type in the whole word yourself and click Enter, nothing happens.